# Node.JS + Jasmine + Protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, protractor, jasmine-node

There are

1. **ActionManager.js** reads files (libraries) with all possible test functions from folder;
2. **WorkflowManager.js** reads files with descriptions of needed tests (test workflow). Each of file contains array of action and arguments.
3. **TestsRunner.js** requires and runs ActionManager and WorkflowManager. After that I want to run each test workflow's action (executes Jasmine test) with arguments.

How to make this process executed **in serious?**

I've tried to implement runner as:

- call require before **describe** block, so Jasmine's tests run before this
- put require into **beforeEach**, so beforeEach is called exactly before executing **it()**; so I know quantity of flows to loop **it()** just after requiring and getting array of flows; but when **it()** executes, it should be already called from already defined loop's iteration
- I put mock describe block with it() for initializing under main describe, but in this case cycle for() get quantuity of flows as 0 and after this all describes starts to execute and quantity is initialized
- I wrapped both decribe into one else -> code between **decribe** and **it**, **describe** and inner **for** cycle doesn't executed.

Here is the part of code with requiring just WorkflowManager and looping for workflows array size with the console output on every iteration.

```
    var firstTime = true;
    beforeEach(function() {
        if (firstTime) {
            var flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow();
            flow.execute(function() {
                console.log("I'm beforeach part#1");
                path = require("path");
                testsPath = path.resolve("./e2e/tests/");
                //requiring WorkflowManager
                wfMng = require('./utils/WorkflowManager.js');
            }).then(function() {
                console.log("I'm beforeeach part#2");
                var workflowPath = path.resolve("./e2e/data/workflows/");
                //getting array of worklows
                wfs = wfMng.getAllWorkflows(workflowPath + '\\');
            }).then(function() {
                console.log("I'm beforeeach part#3");
                //console output of length of workflows array = 1 - is correct
                console.log("Length of array in before each after initing " + wfs.length); //LENGTH = 1
                firstTime = false;
            })
        }
    });


    describe("Describe for initialization", function() {
        it("It block for initialization", function() {
            expect(0).toEqual(0);
            console.log("Length in 1st describe: " + wfs.length); //LENGTH = 1
        });
    });

    describe("Core describe", function() {
        console.log("This console log doesn't executed!!!!");
        //CYCLE ISN'T EXECUTED - LENGTH = 0
        for (var workflowidx = 0, wlen = wfs.length; workflowidx < wlen; workflowidx += 1) {
            (function(widx) {
                console.log("Length in for cycle: " + wfs.length);
                describe("SBB" + widx, function() {
                    console.log("This console log doesn't executed!!!!");
                    it("My test" + widx, function() {
                        expect(2).toEqual(2);
                        console.log("Length in it func: " + wfs.length); //LENGTH = 1
                    });
                });
            })(workflowidx);
        };
    });
```

How to processeed both require, getting arrays of possible actions and needed workflows, and **just after this** executing every action in the loop?

Should I use **Jasmine's spy** somehow?

Node.JS  v0.10.30

Protractor v 1.0.0